# Unable to connect to router-goes to web server instead

Tags: router, ip-address

When I type 192.168.1.1 which is supposed to open up router configuration page, i'm being sent to apache web server's default "it works" page. How to resolve this IP conflict?

This is happening on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I am not behind any firewall.

Comment: What's the output of `ip route`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to access the routers main page you can try:

- Verify IP address and default gateway.
- Clear browser cache and/or restore default settings for the browser.
- Try unpluging the power from the Router wait for 30sec and then
  replug the power to the Router and then try to access the router.
- Reset the router.

Note: Keep in mind that resetting the router will cause all settings to be lost.  Make sure that you have these settings backed up or have it written down somewhere.